# Losing all modification when container is restarted with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i'm using docker docker-compose  for running web application. I want to change inside my container and modify some config file and restarting the container without losing modification .

I'm creating a container using

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Then i run

```
sudo -it -u 0 <container-id> bash
```

After changing in config files everything looks good. If I restart the container executing

```
docker container restart $(docker ps -a -q)
```

all changes where discarded.  Can someone explain to me the best way for doing this without losing modifications  after restart ?

Comment: Depends on whether it is new programs you install or if it is data/configuration changes you have made?

Comment: it is just some changing in config files

Comment: Here is the general guidelines for persistent data in docker https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @David Maze for your reply in my case i have à script for changing many parameters in my app and generating ssl certificat after execution of script in my container i have to restart the contianer

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  wso2iot-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    container_name: wso2iot-mysql
    hostname: wso2iot-mysql
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-uroot", "-proot"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
  wso2iot-broker:
    image: docker.wso2.com/wso2iot-broker:3.3.0
    container_name: wso2iot-broker
    hostname: wso2iot-broker
    ports:
      - "9446:9446"
      - "5675:5675"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "9446"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      wso2iot-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./broker:/home/wso2carbon/volumes/wso2/broker
  wso2iot-analytics:
    image: docker.wso2.com/wso2iot-analytics:3.3.0
    container_name: wso2iot-analytics
    hostname: wso2iot-analytics
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "-f", "https://localhost:9445/carbon/admin/login.jsp"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      wso2iot-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./analytics:/home/wso2carbon/volumes/wso2/analytics
    ports:
      - "9445:9445"
  wso2iot-server:
    image: docker.wso2.com/wso2iot-server:3.3.0
    container_name: wso2iot-server
    hostname: wso2iot-server
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "-f", "https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 120s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      wso2iot-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./iot-server:/home/wso2carbon/volumes
    ports:
      - "9443:9443"
    links:
      - wso2iot-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

A useful technique here is to store a copy of the configuration files on the host and then inject them using a Docker-Compose `volumes:` directive.

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    image: me/myapp
    ports: ['8080:8080']
    volumes:
      - './myapp.ini:/app/myapp.ini'
```

It is fairly routine to destroy and recreate containers, and you want things to be set up so that everything is ready to go immediately once you `docker run` or `docker-compose up`.

Other good uses of bind-mounted directories like this are to give a container a place to publish log files back out, and if your container happens to need persistent data on a filesystem, giving a place to store that across container runs.

`docker exec` is a useful debugging tool, but it is not intended to be part of your core Docker workflow.